# Gradient Editor Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, gradient

I want to include a gradient generator/editor to my code. Qt5 has a gradient editor in designer. I want to use it. I have found this QGradientDialog but i can't make it work.

http://qt.developpez.com/doc/5.0-snapshot/qtgradientdialog/#details

```
 #include <QtGradientDialog>
```

When i include this , i get a not found error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should add both header (*.h) and source (*.cpp) files to your project.

Comment: The Link you provided is from a `Qt 5.0 Snapshot` and I can't find anything about it in the official documentation. Are you sure its in yet?

Comment: I just read that  "Select Gradient" and "Edit Gradient" dialogs (these in Qt Designer) aren't available  as separate dialogs. The sources are located under tools/shared/qtgradienteditor